# Cannot copy files to mtp device using Dolphin/KDE

Tags: mtp

I connected my Samsung smartphone and selected "Copy files" as usb mode on the smartphone.

I then open the smartphone using Dolphin and it shows all folders.

The Problem is I cannot copy files to the device.
It says "file cannot be written" when I paste the file using right click.

Also I did not find a mount path in /run/user nor in /media

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it turned out there is currently a problem copying from a samba share directly to the mtp destination.

As a workaround, I copied the files to my local hard drive and from there to the smartphone/tablet and then it worked.

I used the smb:// kio slave, but it might be a more general kioslave problem.

This was on opensuse 15.4 with a galaxy tab s6.